# Some way of assigning a string to a constant string in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

Here's the scenario, I'm making a class that does regex based on the user specified settings/attributes of the class.

I create public string KeyWords to be able to get the information from the user initially, I can't define that as constant because the value changes based on the user input.

I then somehow need to assign the value in KeyWords to a constant value, because I need to create a new Regex based on those keywords. How might I do it?

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Can you explain why you can only do regex on ONLY a constant, that does not make sense

Comment: @Ryk: I am guessing that the OP doesn't know how to format a non-literal string as a regular expression.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, for variables that should be assigned only once during the lifetime of the class's object, you could consider using ReadOnly fields (better Properties).

That ways, in the constructor of your Settings class, you will be able to assign them with the matched values.

The properties/fields won't be available for assignment after the constructor code is executed.

ReadOnly vs Static: http://weblogs.asp.net/psteele/archive/2004/01/27/63416.aspx

Readonly (MSDN): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7(v=VS.100).aspx

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It either needs to be constant or not, there is no in between.

Why do you think that you need to make `KeyWords` constant at some point?  You cannot enforce a requirement that an argument be constant in C#, so I don't see why you would need this at all.

The [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) class constructors and methods will take any string, just pass in the regular expression to match.

For example, if you have some keywords and want to match any of them, use:

```
keyWords = new List<string> { /* some number of keywords to match */ };
var bldr = new StringBuilder();

// loop through all but the last string to avoid
// a trailing '|' character.
foreach( var s in keyWords.Take( keyWords.Count - 1 ) )
{
    bldr.AppendFormat( "{0}|", s );
}

// get the last one, don't add a '|'
bldr.Append( keyWords.Last() );

var reg = new RegEx( bldr.ToString() );
```

I'm kind of guessing at what you are after here as you don't tell us the problem you are trying to solve, but instead tell us an odd solution you think can make it work.

Answer (score 0):

> I then somehow need to assign the value in KeyWords to a constant value, because I need to create a new Regex based on those keywords.

This doesn't make sense. Why would you need them to be constants to create a `Regex`? Clearly, they aren't constants, by the fact they don't remain constant.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like it should be a `const`. You should only use constants for things that are *never going to change*. For example, `const decimal Pi = 3.14;` makes sense. Your keywords are going to vary every time the application is run, so they shouldn't be constant.

Answer (score 0):

You can still create a regular expression from your user's input keywords, like this:

```
var keyword = "MatchMe";
var regex = new Regex(keyword);
var isMatch = regex.IsMatch("My MatchMe string");
```